# How to set encoding on OS X to reflect default GAE encoding?

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I'm running my Python 2.7 GAE app locally on an OS X machine, and it runs fine. However, when tested on GAE it breaks due to encoding issues. There is an open issue on `code.google.com` that describes the problem: [GAE uses ASCII as its default encoding](http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=2219) but MacOS X uses UTF-8. Is there any way to modify the OS X environment to use ASCII encoding by default?

Comment: Is your problem related to Python or Java?

Comment: Python, should've specified.

Answer (score -1):

System encoding has no impact unless you want to print something to terminal/stdout. In default installation Python has encoding set to ASCII. What error you get exactly?

Comment: It does have an impact, because I get UnicodeDecodeErrors on AppEngine when it tries to use the ASCII codec, but locally I don't get those errors because it's using the UTF-8 codec by default. Nothing is being printed out to terminal/stdout, just HTML parsing using lxml within the app. If there are no encoding issues when running locally, they shouldn't be springing up on GAE.

Comment: Please, provide some traceback you get on production site. Python default encoding can be checked using sys.getdefaultencoding() and should always return 'ascii'. If is not, your Python installation is broken. Unicode errors come usually from passing byte strings where unicode objects are expected.